# CSS Button to top-right corner of image (Gallery)

Tags: html, css, position, gallery

I am trying to position a close button (x) to the top-right corner of an image.

That's just before the footer of my page:

```
<div class="modal" id="modal">
    <span class="close" id="close">✖</span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="modal-content">
</div>
```

How I show the modal:

```
function showModal(name) {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = document.getElementById(name).src;
}
```

And here is my styling:

```
/* Background when image is shown */
#modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(119, 119, 119); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Image */
#modal-content {
    /* Horizontally center image */
    margin: auto;
    /* Sizing */
    display: block;
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: calc(100vh * 0.5);
    width: auto;
    /* Zoom (image gets bigger) on open */
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
    /* Style */
    border: 10px solid #ffffff;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54) 0px 0px 7px 4px;
    /* Vertically center image */
    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translateY(-40%);
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {
        transform: scale(0)
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1)
    }
}

/* Close Button */
#close {
    /* Position */
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    /* Style */
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 25px 3px;
    /* Makes the Button round */
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}

/* Change cursor when pointing on button */
#close:hover,
#close:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% image width on smaller screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

The problem is that

```
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 10px;
```

positions the close button in the top-right corner of the page, not at the top right corner of the image.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `close` element it's positioning relative to the closest positioned ancestor, in your case the `modal` div instead of the `modal-content` (as you wanted).

I recomend you to wrap either the `modal-content` and `close` "button" in a (relative) div, like this:

```
<div class="modal" id="modal">
    <div id='modal-content' class='modal-content">
       <span class="close" id="close">✖</span>
       <img> //make img height/width to 100%
    </div>
</div>
```

This should position the close button in the top-right position of the absolute div and the image inside this div.

If the close button doesn't appear, make sure it has a higher `z-index` than the image.

I made a codepen: https://codepen.io/jpaulet/pen/RwGxpxy

Comment: That works so far pretty good, but now the border around the image is much larger than the image. The border is nearly about 90% wide and the image inside of it is on the left side, while the right side is completely empty. Do you have an idea how I can do the styling?

Comment: I can of course put the border around the img instead of around modal-content, but still the image is close to the left and the button is close to the right.

Comment: I was now able to fix that using `width: max-content;`. Thanks.

Comment: Nice, I also edit my answer with a codepen to show how it could work (I think that is what you are looking)

Comment: I had to do some changes to resize the image and now I have a similar problem. It would be great, if you have a look at it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65484753/positioning-buttons-next-to-image)