# Positioning buttons next to image

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

**I already asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65478447/css-button-to-top-right-corner-of-image-gallery)**, but now I have changed a few styles and have no idea how I can **position the close button to the top-right corner** of the image as well as the **previous and next buttons** on the left and right side of the image **with a given distance to it**.

That's just before the footer of my page:

```
<div class="modal" id="modal">
    <div id="modal-content">
        <span class="gallery-button" id="close">✖</span>
        <span class="gallery-button" id="previous">◄</span>
        <span class="gallery-button" id="next">►</span>
        <img id="modal-image">
    </div>
</div>
```

How I show the modal:

```
function showModal(directory, response, i) {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = document.getElementById(path(directory, response[i])).src;

    /* previousButton.style.display = "block"; */
    /* nextButton.style.display = "block"; */
}
```

And here is my styling:

```
/* Background when image is shown */
#modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    /* Position */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    /* Sizing */
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(119, 119, 119); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.7); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Image wrapper */
#modal-content {
    /* Sizing */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Image */
#modal-image {
    /* Sizing */
    max-width: 80%;
    height: calc(100vh * 0.6);
    /* Style */
    border: 10px solid #ffffff;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54) 0px 0px 7px 4px;
    /* Horizontally center image */
    margin: auto;
    /* Zoom (image gets bigger) on open */
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
    /* Vertically center image */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {
        transform: scale(0)
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1)
    }
}

/* Gallery Buttons */
.gallery-button {
    /* Style */
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 25px 3px;
    /* Makes the Button round */
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* Previous Button */
#previous {
    font-size: 12px;
    /* Position */
    position: absolute;
    /* Horizontally */
    left: 30px;
    /* Vertically */
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/* Next Button */
#next {
    font-size: 12px;
    /* Position */
    position: absolute;
    /* Horizontally */
    right: 30px;
    /* Vertically */
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/* Close Button */
#close {
    font-size: 15px;
    /* Position */
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 30px;
}

/* Change cursor when pointing on button */
.gallery-button:hover,
.gallery-button:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% image width on smaller screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Currently the close button is in the top right corner of the whole page and the previous and next buttons already centered vertically (which is good), but not yet near the image. How can I kind of attach the buttons to the image. Sizing the image was kind of hard and I have no idea how I can do it in a different way, so that I can put the sized image and the buttons in a `div`.

Comment: It would help a lot if you'd be able to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That way we can experience your code without having to imagine what it would look like. Try to omit code that isn't necessary for your question.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it's easier to understand now.

Comment: in `#modal-content` style try adding `position: relative`. It won't disturb the wrapper at all, but it will set the children's positions relative to it, instead of its parent.

Comment: I added the line to #modal-content, but it doesn't change anything at all. Would I have to add any other style attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ruled out your CSS. Because it's really messy. But If you check this code below, you could understand how to set positioning. Hope you can do the rest of the work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #modal-content{
      position: relative;
      width:50%;
      height:50%;
    }
    #modal-image{
      width:100%;
      height:auto;
    }
    #close{
      position: absolute;
      right: 0px;
      top: 0px;
    }
    #previous{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 1%;
      
    }
    #next{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 1%;
      
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="modal" id="modal">
    <div id="modal-content">
        
        
        <img id="modal-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/vga" alt="">
        <span class="gallery-button" id="close">✖</span>
        <span class="gallery-button" id="previous">◄</span>
        <span class="gallery-button" id="next">►</span>
        
    </div>
</div>
<script>
  function showModal(directory, response, i) {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = document.getElementById(path(directory, response[i])).src;

    /* previousButton.style.display = "block"; */
    /* nextButton.style.display = "block"; */
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update code (as a requirement)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #modal{
          width:100vw;
          height: 100vh;
      }
    #modal-content{
      position: relative;
      width:35%;
      height:90%;
    }
    #modal-image{
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
    }
    #close{
      position: absolute;
      right: 0px;
      top: 0px;
    }
    #previous{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 1%;
      
    }
    #next{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 1%;
      
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="modal" id="modal">
    <div id="modal-content">
        
        
        <img id="modal-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/vga" alt="">
        <span class="gallery-button" id="close">✖</span>
        <span class="gallery-button" id="previous">◄</span>
        <span class="gallery-button" id="next">►</span>
        
    </div>
</div>
<script>
  function showModal(directory, response, i) {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = document.getElementById(path(directory, response[i])).src;

    /* previousButton.style.display = "block"; */
    /* nextButton.style.display = "block"; */
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, you already helped a lot. The problem now is that I don't know the height of `modal-content`. I can set the width to let's say 35%, but I want the height to be so that the image keeps it's aspect ratio. As modal-content isn't the image itself, I have no idea how I can do that. When I set it to 100% (so that the height of the image is determined by `height:auto` in `modal-image`, the close button is of course at the top of the page.

Comment: I was now able to fix that, but for some reason the image is bigger than `modal-content`. How can that happen, if I set `width: 100%`? You can see it here: [link](https://ibb.co/j4S9CFc). Furthermore, how can I specify a `max-height`? Setting the `max-height` attribute for `modal-content` just makes `modal-content` smaller. For `modal-content` I've set `width: 35%; height: auto;` and for `modal-image` `width: 100%; height: auto;`

Comment: To summarize what I have written above: my last problem is that I don't know how to set the maximum height of the image to 90% of the screen height.

Comment: If I understand you properly, make **100vw** and **100vh** on the parent Div. So that parent div can take **100% width** and **100% height** from entire screen. After that, make your **modal-content** with **width:35%** and **height:90%** (as your requirement). Now make your **modal-image** **width:100%** and **height:100%** . I have updated my main answer. Check there for better understanding. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your help, but that unfortunately doesn't work as the image doesn't keep its apect ratio when I use width and height for modal-content at the same time. If you don't have a different idea I might have to leave it as it is, even if it's not 100% perfect (doesn't work on mobile devices rotated to landscape).